# How to create a public server in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, httplistener

I am a novice programmer. I was trying to learn about networking in C#. I want to know how to create a public server in C#. I tried to search on the internet but I didn't find much. As a public server, I meant to connect to one computer to another from remote or an online server where I can connect from anywhere which is written in C#. I want to know is how to make it and what I need to do that or especially I want the information how can I make one and what I need. I would like to use winform/wpf or console application for the server.(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources out there already, you just need to do your research.

A couple notes:

1. winform/wpf is a technology for desktop programs, with windows and user controls and such. A server has no need for such things.
2. a server is a server, public or not. Making it public is as simple as making it available at an IP address / domain that is reachable from the internet. This has little to do with implementation.
3. there are so, so, so many different types of server applications. Some serve websites, others serve databases, and still others just provide raw data in the form of JSON or XML.

I'm assuming since you're just getting started, you're trying to build a web server to serve a website. Here's a tutorial I found by Googling 'c# web server' that seems to get you up and running: https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server

Good luck, and remember that SO is a place for technical questions, not a 'how to do a whole thing start to finish' forum :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the keywords you need are

- ASP.NET + IIS, for a full fledged server app
- HttpListener, for a stand alone server app

The prior is a framework for building a MVC Server application (it also has a subset called WebApi which as the name states is for APIs), and the latter is the class you will need to create a stand alone server application.

In the future, you might want to consider using ASP.NET Core to deploy your application onto linux.

Good luck.